# Join with Like in Views Plugin

Tags: 8, views, database

Attempting to do a join with a LIKE operand in a Views filter plugin.  The query looks similar to below; however, when it executes, the LIKE operand is not taken into account and the join is done with '='.  Is there a way to do this type of join?

```
$configuration = [
     'type' => 'INNER',
     'table' => 'path_alias',
     'field' => 'CONCAT(\'%\', path_alias.path)',
     'left_table' => 'redirect',
     'left_field' => 'redirect_redirect__uri',
     'operator' => 'LIKE',];

   $join = Views::pluginManager('join')->createInstance('standard', $configuration);
   $this->query->addRelationship('path', $join, 'path_alias');
```

This is the query we are trying to execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM redirect AS redirect
INNER JOIN path_alias AS path ON 
  redirect.redirect_redirect__uri LIKE CONCAT('%', path.path);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch available that provides a solution to this problem: https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2981544.